# $T_{\infty}=(U|(X−U) \ is\ infinite \ or \ empty \ or \ all \ of \ X)$ a topology on X?

Tags: general-topology

I know that there is another question about the same problem, but my question concerns an answer that I've found on the internet. (Which is highly likely to be true)

> Is the collection 
>   $T_{\infty}=(U|(X−U) \ is\ infinite \ or \ empty \ or \ all \ of \ X)$
>
> a topology on X?

It's easy to prove that $X \in T$ and $\emptyset \in T$.

The proof is on : https://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-13-basis-for-a-topology/problem-3-solution/

My concern is about how did we assume countability in the proof?

Comment: An infinite set is at least countable.

Comment: Could they have been talking about T_c?

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas Well, depending on the definitions of "infinite" and "countable" this might actually require the Axiom of Choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ \ $U$ is finite then  $T_{\infty}=\{\phi, U,X\}$ is a topology on $X.$

If $X$ \ $U$ is infinite , and  $X$ \ $U=A\cup B$ where $A,B$ are infinite and $A\cap B=\phi$  then take $p\in A .$ Then $A$ and  $B\cup \{p\}$ are in $T_{\infty}$ but $A\cap (B\cup \{p\})=\{p\}\not \in T_{\infty},$ so $T_{\infty}$ is not a topology on $X.$

Example: $X=\Bbb N$ and $U=\phi$ and $A=\{2n:n\in \Bbb N\}$ and $B=\{2n-1:n\in \Bbb N\}$ and $p=2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not topology. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and suppose the $T_{\infty}$ is topology on $X$. Then $U=(-\infty,0)$ and $V=(0,\infty)$ are open with $T_{\infty}$. Then $U\cup V$ must be open, then $X|(U\cup V)=\{0\}$ is must be $\emptyset$ or infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X:=\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $U_1:=\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$.
Let $U_2:=\{0,-1,-2,-3,\dots\}$.
Then, $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{T_{\infty}}$.
But $U_1\cap U_2=\{0\}\notin\mathcal{T_{\infty}}$.
So, $\mathcal{T}_{\infty}$ is not a topology on $X$.